# Backendless - Composição do table id

Tags: tabela-html, back-end

Olá!

Eu criei uma `table` no Backendless e eu gostaria de saber se eu posso compor o `table id` com 2 campos como em uma `SQL table`. É possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Backendless cria automaticamente um identificador único para cada objeto inserido. É uma coluna do sistema chamada `objectId`.